# BrowserStack Local Testing + Cypress: local HTML file

Tags: browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I have a frontend app, and the final result of the build command is a single HTML file: index.html

I have cypress tests for it, validating the index.html file shows visually perfect: `cy.visit('./dist/index.html')`. I do not need to serve the `index.html` file over HTTP to be able to test it. Cypress automatically picks it up and I'm happy with it.

Now I need to do the same test in BrowserStack. So far I had no luck being able to run BrowserStack against local HTML files. I've followed the tutorials and docs, they mostly work when you serve your app over HTTP (e.g. `cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')`) which works for me too.

But I constantly receive this error:

```
`cy.visit()` failed trying to load: ./dist/index.html The response we received from your web server was: > 502: Bad Gateway This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx`. If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: `failOnStatusCode: false`
```

error stack on BrowserStack:

```
`cy.visit()` failed trying to load:

./dist/index.html

The response we received from your web server was:

  > 502: Bad Gateway

This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx`.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: `failOnStatusCode: false`
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:147661:84)
    at visitFailedByErr (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:147069:12)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:147644:13)
    at tryCatcher (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:18744:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:16679:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:16736:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:16781:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:16857:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13451:12)
    at _drainQueue (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13444:9)
    at ../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13460:5)
    at Async.drainQueues (http://localhost:29070/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:13330:14)
From Your Spec Code:
    at eval (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/visual-test.cy.js:22:7)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Context.eval (webpack:///./cypress/e2e/visual-test.cy.js:17:13)
```

simplified test code:

```
cy.visit(`./test/output/banner/index.html?seek=${time}`);
cy.get('#stage > :nth-child(2)').should('be.visible');
cy.compareSnapshot(`snapshot of page`);
```

## What I tried so far

- I tried copying the result `index.html` file in different places of my project (root folder, beside cypress test and beside cypress config), did not help
- I tried passing `folder ./dist` and `folder dist/` to YML file and passed that YML file as `local_config_file` in `connection_settings`.
- I tried manually running local BrowserStack binary and point to its identifier in `connection_settings.local_identifier`. And also removing `connection_settings.local_identifier` when running BrowserStack bimary locally
- running simply `./BrowserStackLocal --key <MY_KEY>` also does not allow me to see `file:///index.html` in BrowserStack live session

Answer (score 1):

Could you try upgrading the BrowserStack Cypress CLi, because I can see that the support for uploading .HTML files was added recently.

[Link for reference](https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-cypress-cli/releases#:%7E:text=Public%20Beta%20v1.22.1-,Highlights%20of%20the%20changes)